# How can I change the icons of many folders?

Tags: nautilus, folder

I have a collection of films on my computer and every film is stored in its own folder with image of its cover.

What I would like to do is to change icon of each folder to icon of film's cover. Is there any way to do this quicker than right-clicking on each folder and changing icons manually?

Comment: My acquirement also same!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this from the command line:

```
gvfs-set-attribute -t string <directory> metadata::custom-icon file://<icon-location>
```

replacing `<directory>` with the name of the directory you want a custom icon for and `<icon-location>` with the location of the icon. For example, to change the icon of ~/Documents to a red apple:

```
gvfs-set-attribute -t string ~/Documents metadata::custom-icon file:///usr/share/pixmaps/apple-red.png
```

Now, to automate the process a bit, say that you have a directory `~/Videos/Films` inside which you have one directory per film, each of which containing a file called `icon.png` that contains the desired icon. In that case you can type at the command line:

```
{ while read -r d ; do [ -d "$d" ] && [ -e "$d/icon.png" ] || continue ; gvfs-set-attribute -t string "$d" metadata::custom-icon "file://$d/icon.png" ; done ; } < <(find ~/Videos/Films -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d)
```

Notice that an open nautilus window will need to be refreshed in order for any icon changes performed on the command line to take effect.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you very much.

Comment: For Igor Cavour Oliveira: In that case you can type at the command line:" how can i write this comand line in an shellscript instead of in the shell?