# Change folder icon of multiple folders (movies)

Tags: command-line, nautilus, directory

[How can I change the icons of many folders?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97484/how-can-i-change-the-icons-of-many-folders?newreg=37a68fbc8cb64606bb4d44c459100487)

[How to set the first picture of every folders as their folder icons?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/796256/how-to-set-the-first-picture-of-every-folders-as-their-folder-icons)

I've been here but it doesn't work for me. Because my movies aren't in the home partition they are in a different ext4 partition and when I try to put the location of that partition in that command it simply doesn't work because it automatically puts */home/sumeet* in front of the location that I type.

Scripts in the 2nd post aren't working! Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

[EDIT 2 DETAILED]

```
{ while read -r d ; do [ -d "$d" ] && [ -e "$d/folder.png" ] || continue ; gvfs-set-attribute -t string "$d" metadata::custom-icon "file://$d/folder.png" ; done ; } < <(find ~/mnt/c2104e2a-cc8e-4b7b-9bba-a05d316472b4/I -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d)
```

I ran this command first from the first post, which gave me an out put

```
find: ‘/home/sumeet/mnt/c2104e2a-cc8e-4b7b-9bba-a05d316472b4/I’: No such file or directory
```

Then I moved some of the files to *home/videos/films* as suggested in the orignal post and ran this command

```
{ while read -r d ; do [ -d "$d" ] && [ -e "$d/folder.png" ] || continue ; gvfs-set-attribute -t string "$d" metadata::custom-icon "file://$d/folder.png" ; done ; } < <(find ~/Videos/Films -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d)
```

Which worked perfectly fine but i can't move my entire film collection to home folder.

Then I tried the solution in the 2nd mentioned post and ran

```
python3 /home/sumeet/change_icon.py </mnt/c2104e2a-cc8e-4b7b-9bba-a05d316472b4/I>
```

And got this output

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

Then I figured, I did something wrong and tried this

```
python3 /home/sumeet/change_icon.py /mnt/c2104e2a-cc8e-4b7b-9bba-a05d316472b4/I
```

Didn't get any output but it didn't work either.

Then I tried the second script 3 or 4 times. Right click option appeared but it didn't work, and I've done everything both the posts asked. I logged out, logged back in, I tried rebooting, `-q nautilus`

Doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Post the actual command you ran. How do we know what you did wrong if you don't show us?

Comment: On the second script, the targeted directory is argument. I don't see that in the command you ran. Unless you ran the right-click option, in which case you should not run it as a separate script, but only from nautilus.

Comment: Jacob jlijm, can you elaborate a little, because I'm completely new to this!

Comment: Is their any other way I can try from the beginning?

Comment: right click thing worked! linux is best

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### This script was written by [Jacob Vlijm](https://askubuntu.com/users/72216/jacob-vlijm) and was originally posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/796256/how-to-set-the-first-picture-of-every-folders-as-their-folder-icons).

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os

# --- set the list of valid extensions below (lowercase)
# --- use quotes, *don't* include the dot!
ext = ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "icns", "ico"]
# ---

# retrieve the path of the targeted folder
current = os.getenv("NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI").replace("file://", "").replace("%20", " ")
dr = os.path.realpath(current)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dr):
    for directory in dirs:
        folder = os.path.join(root, directory)
        try:
            first = min(p for p in os.listdir(folder) 
                        if p.split(".")[-1].lower() in ext)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
              subprocess.Popen([
                  "gvfs-set-attribute", "-t", "string",
                  os.path.abspath(folder), "metadata::custom-icon",
                  "file://"+os.path.abspath(os.path.join(folder, first))
                  ])
```

#### To use

1. Create, if it doesn't exist yet, the directory

   ```
   ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts
   ```
2. Copy the script into an empty file, save it in `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts` as `set_foldericons` (no extension!), right click and go to file properties and **make it executable**.
3. Log out and back in, it works.

If you want to hide all the folder icons (so that you don't accidentally presume they are folders) add a `.` at the start of file names, for example `folder.png` becomes `.folder.png`

[image: all set, with one script]

[Original work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/796256/how-to-set-the-first-picture-of-every-folders-as-their-folder-icons)

Comment: Since you're using Python, use [`urllib.parse.unquote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote) and `urllib.parse.urlparse` to properly extract file paths from the URI that nautilus provides.

Comment: @muru I am new to this, can you edit the answer to reflect the changes you're suggesting?